# Copy spreadsheet/time trigger doesn't work but manual trigger works well

Tags: google-apps-script

Just wonder whether anyone can help me? I am a newbie to Apps Script, even not a professional developer.

The purpose of my below codes is to pull data of Android App from Appsflyer into ExportTemp sheet, then copy the data rows to the last row of another sheet Daily_Android, then remove any duplicated rows. then do the same for the iOS data.

It runs well when I manually run the codes, but the cloneGoogleSheet() function doesn't work when time-triggered, although the log said it runs successfully, but the AppsflyerExport() function did run well.  that is, the appsflyer data was pulled into the ExportTem sheet, but it was not copied into the Daily_Android sheet when time-triggered(once a day).

thanks a lot

Jason

```
   function AppsflyerMain(){

  var spreadSheetID = '******';
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadSheetID);
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(spreadSheet);
 var MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
 var now = new Date();
 var from = new Date(now.getTime() - 1 * MILLIS_PER_DAY);
 var to = new Date(now.getTime() - 1 * MILLIS_PER_DAY);
 //export Android 
   var fromDate = Utilities.formatDate(from, 'Asia/Jakarta', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
   var toDate = Utilities.formatDate(to, 'Asia/Jakarta', 'yyyy-MM-dd');

   var appID = '****';
   var apiToken = '****';
   var reportType = 'daily_report';
   var sourceSheetName = 'ExportTemp';
   var datastoreSheetName = 'Daily_Android';

   var sheet_andr = spreadSheet.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);
  if (sheet_andr == null) {
      sheet_andr = spreadSheet.insertSheet(sourceSheetName);
      }

  AppsflyerExport(sheet_andr,appID, apiToken,reportType,fromDate,toDate);
  cloneGoogleSheet(spreadSheetID, spreadSheetID, sourceSheetName,datastoreSheetName);
  removeDuplicates(spreadSheetID,datastoreSheetName);

  //export iOS
    appID = '****';
    apiToken = '*****';
    reportType = 'daily_report';
    sourceSheetName = 'ExportTempiOS';
    datastoreSheetName = 'Daily_iOS';

    var sheet_ios = spreadSheet.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);
  if (sheet_ios == null) {
      sheet_ios = spreadSheet.insertSheet(sourceSheetName);
      }

  AppsflyerExport(sheet_ios,appID, apiToken,reportType,fromDate,toDate);
  cloneGoogleSheet(spreadSheetID, spreadSheetID, sourceSheetName,datastoreSheetName);
  removeDuplicates(spreadSheetID,datastoreSheetName);
}

function AppsflyerExport(sheet,appID,apiToken, reportType,fromDate, toDate){

     request_url = '=importdata("https://hq.appsflyer.com/export/'+appID+'/'+reportType+'/v5?api_token='+ apiToken + '&from='+fromDate+'&to='+toDate+'")';
      sheet.clear({contentsOnly: true});

      sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(request_url); 
  }

function cloneGoogleSheet(ssAID,ssBID,sourceSheet,targetSheet) {
var ssA = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssAID);
var ssB = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssBID);
  // source sheet
  var ss = ssA.getSheetByName(sourceSheet);
   if (ss == null) {
      ss = ssA.insertSheet(sourceSheet);
      }
  // Get full range of data, exclude first row the title row

  var SRange = ss.getRange(2, 1, ss.getMaxRows(), ss.getMaxColumns());

  // target sheet
  var ts = ssB.getSheetByName(targetSheet); 

  if (ts == null) {
      ts = ssB.insertSheet(targetSheet);
      }

  var TRange = ts.getDataRange();
  var ts_numRows = TRange.getNumRows();
  var ts_nextRow = ts_numRows +1;
Logger.log('last row of ' + targetSheet + ' is ' + ts_numRows);
console.log('last row of ' + targetSheet + ' is ' + ts_numRows);
  //copy source data to last row of target sheet
  SRange.copyTo(ts.getRange(ts_nextRow, 1));
 Logger.log('copied new data from row '+ts_nextRow);
 console.log('copied new data from row '+ts_nextRow);
};



function removeDuplicates(ssID, sheetName) {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = [];
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for (var j in newData) {
      if (row.join() == newData[j].join()) {    // this is to check the duplicate of whole row
      //if(row[0] == newData[j][0] ){
  duplicate = true;
}
    }
    if (!duplicate) {
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you realize you are sending the same sheet ID to cloneGoogleSheet twice? And thus opening it twice as two different names in that function?

Comment: does it matter?

Comment: yes? it is trying to copy from the same "targetname" sheet to  the same sheet" and then remove duplicates. How will you know if it has run at all? The removal of the duplicates will get rid of all evidence you did anything.

Comment: hmm, but when I manually open the spreadsheet,  trigger the code, it runs very well as I planned, pull data from Appsflyer to ExportTemp sheet, then copy it into the last row of Daily_Android sheet.